# Showing a Q-variety is irreducible.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f(x,y)=x^2-2y^2\in{\mathbb{Q[x,y]}}$ then I am not sure how we can show that $V(\{f\})$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-variety is irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $V$ is irreducible iff. $I(V)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.    (**)

Now $I(V)$ is just the ideal generated by $f$ in this case, and since $\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, you can conclude that $f$ is irreducible. You can reference (**) in Knapp's Introduction to Algebraic Geometry.

Admittedly, I am just starting algebraic geometry, and clearly $V_f$ is only an algebraic set when we are working in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, but the one thing I have picked up so far is to be very careful about which field we are in.

Comment: How do you conclude $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ just by saying $\sqrt{2}\not\in{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: We are considering the algebraically closed field as $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Q[x,y]}$ your factorization of $f$ does not work. But over $\mathbb{R[x,y]}$, you are perfectly right and $I(V)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R[x,y]}$.

Comment: See Hungerford's book in "Algebra" GTM 73 Section VIII.7 on p. 409.

Comment: Finally, my last comment...a direct quote from my professor "the literature in this subject is a mess". I hope that helps...always be thinking about what fields you want to be in, as you can see, prime may be prime here but not there. irreducible? perhaps here, but not there.

Comment: Okay, I think I am caught up to you now. I see question 8. (b). It seems to me he has change his definition from page 409 for this question yes? Hmmm. thats confusing. In his definition, he is in F, then he states K-variety in terms of F, then in the question he switches over to Q and R? is it just me?

Comment: Finally, finally, bottom line, in that question he doesn't want you to be in the affine n-space, he wants you to be in the set of rational points... Q in the first part, then R in the second part.

Comment: as for irreducibility of $f$, we have $x^2 -2y^2=0$. now try to find a polynomial in $y$ that we can substitute for $x$ that satisfies $f$. E.g. we are in Q[y][x]....we would require $\sqrt{2}y$ to reside in Q[y].